# CSS bundle is empty when EnableOptimizations is true

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, bundling-and-minification

I am creating a style bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/bundled-styles.css").Include(
    "~/content/flexisel-style.css"));
```

... and in my view:

```
@Styles.Render("~/content/bundled-styles.css")
```

If I view my page without optimizations enabled (i.e. `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;`) then everything works fine. My .css file gets added to the page without any problems and it contains all the styles.

If I set `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` (without changing *anything* else) then the generated .css bundle doesn't contain any styles. The bundled .css file is added to the page along with the generated token but when I click on the .css file from the page source, it is completely blank. My page then is obviously rendered without any styling.

Additional information:

- I do not have a file or a folder called "bundled-styles.css" in my content folder
- This is the only bundle I am adding.
- I am not receiving any error (like a 404). The .css file is simply empty.
- I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.

Comment: try removing the file and extension on the virtual path `"~/content/bundled-styles.css"` to `"~/content/css"`

Comment: @Shoe Thanks for the suggestion but no luck. Same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had this issue as well.
It seems as if the bundler did not like the extension in the name. Once I removed the extension, the bundler started to work.

You might try doing the following. Notice I've removed the `.css` in two places.

**Remove the .css**

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/bundled-styles").Include(
    "~/content/flexisel-style.css"));
```

---

```
@Styles.Render("~/content/bundled-styles")
```

Comment: In case others have this issue too, this happened to me with my bundle name ending in "/css" and "/js" not specifically with extensions. Switched them to "/styles" and "/scripts" and now they work.

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck on this for a very long time, i was trapped by the following:

> that if the key you’re using for your bundle, in this case
>   “~/scripts”, matches the virtual path of the file included in the
>   bundle, then it will not be included. To fix this, I changed the key
>   to “~/bundles/scripts” and everything is happy now.

Credits: https://samrueby.com/2015/03/05/asp-net-mvc-bundleconfig-scripts-returning-an-empty-response/